# Contagem de distancia entre um elemento e cada um dos outros numa lista (Python)

Tags: python, lógica

Eu tenho uma lista que simboliza uma linha do tempo:

```
linha_tempo = [1107, 1107, 0, 1104, 1104, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1106, 1106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1102, 1102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1105, 1105, 1101, 1101, 0, 0, 1103, 1103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

O que eu preciso daqui é armazenar as distâncias em que cada primeira ocorrência de um elemento diferente de 0 está do proximo elemento diferente de 0.

Ex: 1107 está a uma distância de 3 de 1104, para 1106 está a 36... e assim por diante, tenho de fazer isto para todos os elementos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor maneira para armazenar os dados é usando um dicionário. Pode fazer assim:

```
distancias = {}
lenLT = len(linha_tempo)
for i in range(0, lenLT):
    if(linha_tempo[i] != 0 and linha_tempo[i] != linha_tempo[i+1]): # caso encontremos um elemento diferente de 0 e o elemento a seguir seja diferente (nao vale a pensa fazer isto duas vezes seguidas, que e o numero de ocorrencias de elementos dif de 0
        distancias[linha_tempo[i]] = {} # criamos uma chave do dicionario com elemento diferente de 0 encontrado
        distancia = 0 # resetamos a distancia
        for j in range(i, lenLT): # comecamos a contar a partir do index onde foi descoberto o elemento ate ao fim
            distancia += 1 # incrementamos 1 a distancia
            if(linha_tempo[j] == 0 or linha_tempo[j] == linha_tempo[i]): # nao vale continuar na iteracao se o elemento for 0 ou se for a segunda ocorrencia do elemento encontrado
                continue
            if(linha_tempo[j] not in distancias[linha_tempo[i]]):
                distancias[linha_tempo[i]][linha_tempo[j]] = distancia #armazenamos a chave (elemento deferente de 0, linha_tempo[j]) com a respetiva distancia (de linha_tempo[i] ate linha_tempo[j])
```

Resultado:

```
print(distancias) # {1104: {1105: 58, 1106: 33, 1101: 60, 1102: 40, 1103: 64}, 1105: {1101: 2, 1103: 6}, 1106: {1105: 25, 1101: 27, 1102: 7, 1103: 31}, 1107: {1104: 3, 1105: 61, 1106: 36, 1101: 63, 1102: 43, 1103: 67}, 1101: {1103: 4}, 1102: {1105: 18, 1101: 20, 1103: 24}, 1103: {}}
```

Tento explicar a lógica nos comentários espero que perceba, senão diga que eu tento melhorar

Comment: Ótimo @Miguel, muito obrigado! Me ajudou muito! Consegui entender perfeitamente a lógica, por causa dos comentários!

Comment: De nada @Allan. Ainda bem que percebeu e resolveu